# get annotation path of web services in java

Tags: java, annotations

i've a class call Vtiger_Services in which I have a lot of web services methods... I want to get the annotation of every web services and store it as a string in arraylist

example web services in Vtiger_Services:

```
    @Path("getCustomers")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getCustomers(@HeaderParam("token") String token) {
    if (token.equalsIgnoreCase(this.token)) {
        String sql = "select * from tab1";
        Database db = new Database();
        String json = db.executeQueryTOJSON(sql);
        return json;
    } else
        return "{\"error\":\"bad token provided\"}";
}
```

I want to get the vaule of @Path

I made this method to get the name

```
for(int i = 0; i < Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods().length; i++)
            {
                if(Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()[i].getParameters().length > 0 && 
                   Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()[i].getParameters()[0].getType().getSimpleName().equals("String") &&
                   Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()[i].getReturnType().getSimpleName().equals("String"))
                {
                        con.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO Services (Name) VALUES ('"+ Vtiger_Services.class.getDeclaredMethods()[i].getName()+"')");

                }                                                           
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are getting currently and what you expect to receive? Also a sample dataset would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use java refection to get classes methods and then look for annotations on these methods.

```
public class Test {
    @Path("getCustomers")
    public void test() {

    }

    public static List<String> getMethodsAnnotatedWith(final Class<?> type) {
        final List<String> paths = Lists.newArrayList();
        Class<?> clazz = type;
        while (clazz != Object.class) {
            final List<Method> allMethods = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredMethods()));
            for (final Method method : allMethods) {
                Path path = method.getAnnotation(Path.class);
                if(path != null) {
                    paths.add(path.value());
                }
            }
            // move to the upper class in the hierarchy in search for more methods
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }
        return paths;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Test.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: I update with the method to get the name of every web services.. 
how can i modify it to get the annotations?

Comment: Can you give more details? Compilation or Runtime error?